# Xcode Issue can't get code working

Tags: xcode, mobile

When I tried to execute this XCODE an error occured. Can anyone help me understand it please? The Error is at line 5.

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @interface BIDViewController : UIViewController
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
   - (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
   [sender resignFirstResponder];
   @end
```

Thanks.

Comment: @op please post the error message.

Comment: Please read a tutorial on Objective-C programming.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> [sender resignFirstResponder];
> ```

You can't do that in a `.h` file. Remove it. That belongs in `.m`.

Answer (score 0):

in .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BIDViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
```

in .m

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```